# How should I get about checking if an object is at a certain position in sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

Hi writing a program just for fun to practitce sfml. I made the dvd logo screen (the one where it bounces from point to point but i want to check if it collides at the corner so I can change the color. How do I check if it collides with the corner?

```cpp
      window.clear();
            window.draw(shape);

        if (x_direction==1){
            shape.move(0.05,0);
        }

        if (x_direction==2){
            shape.move(-0.05,0);
        }

        if (y_direction==1){
            shape.move(0,0.05);
        }

        if (y_direction==2){
            shape.move(0,-0.05);
        }

        if (shape.getPosition()==)
        //draw objects here
        window.display();
        if (shape.getPosition().x + shape.getLocalBounds().width >= window.getSize().x ) {
            x_direction =2;
        }
        if (shape.getPosition().x <= 0 ) {
            x_direction=1;
        }
        if (shape.getPosition().y <= 0 ) {
            y_direction=1;
        }
        if (shape.getPosition().y + shape.getLocalBounds().height >= window.getSize().y ) {
            y_direction=2;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Trying to use get Position but will this be affected by the size of the object?

Comment: Does your current code not work? Besides your erroneous `if(shape.getPosition()==)` the bounds checking looks fine. The size of the object will affect its position, but presumably `getLocalBounds` handles that already (so if its scale is 50% the `width` would be smaller) otherwise you could add scale adjusting in. Please [edit] your question to include what your code currently does, if it's not working correctly.

Comment: @Tas Was just trying to figure it out and got it all to work last night. Really new to sfml (downloaded on Friday) so just trying to test things out.